# Determine if mouse over over element while having an element "dragged"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement an "drag to sort" function on this [page](http://bit.ly/1q3itLo). On the right side there are thumbnails which I want to be able to order. I thought to use jQuery's sortable in `jQuery UI`. But it seems to be a bit odd since my thumbnails are scaled through `CSS` and then it does not work correctly.

Now I have made something what is basically. When I have a mouse down event on a thumbnail, I clone it hide the original and put the cloned element where my mouse is. But now when I hover (while having the cloned element under my cursor) over another thumbnail the hover event is not fired for that thumbnail.

Is there another way to determine if my cursus is above a certain element in the `DOM`? E.g so I can detect that the cursor is above another thumbnail while dragging a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was fast. This `CSS` on the item which is dragged seems to do the trick.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: I'm curious what any of your actual code is here, as a sortable list with items scaled by CSS sounds like an atypical use case, and I'm not clear how stopping all pointer events would have solved your problem.

Comment: If you click the page, the items on the side are the "thumbnails" of the items on the left. Like in OSX Preview for example. I want to be able to drag the items on the right to order.

Comment: I was going to use this but i still need `onmouseup` to fire for the dragged element when it is dropped. `pointer-events: none;` stops `onmouseup` from firing as it is a pointer event and none means none lol.